# what is the use of _spark_metadata directory

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to get my head around how streaming works in `spark`.

I have a file in a `/data/flight-data/csv/` directory. It has the following data:

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States       Romania             15
United States       Croatia             1
United States       Ireland             344
Egypt               United States       15
```

I thought to test what will happen if I read the file as a stream instead of as a batch. I first created a `Dataframe` using `read`

```
scala> val dataDF = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").csv("data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv");
[Stage 0:>                                                                                                            dataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

then took the schema fromm it and created a new `Dataframe`

```
scala> val staticSchema = dataDF.schema;
staticSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true), StructField(ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true), StructField(count,IntegerType,true))

scala> val dataStream = spark.readStream.schema(staticSchema).option("header","true").csv("data/flight-data/csv");
dataStream: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

Then I started the stream. The path for checkpoint and output (I suppose) is `/home/manu/test" directory which is initially empty.

```
scala> dataStream.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation","home/manu/test").start("/home/manu/test");
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@5c7df5f1
```

The return value of the `start` is `StreamingQuery` which I read is `A handle to a query that is executing continuously in the background as new data arrives. All these methods are thread-safe.`

I notice that now the directory has a directory `_spark_metadata`but there is nothing else.

Question1 - What is `_spark_metadata` directory? I notice it is empty. What is it used for?

Question 2 - I don't see anything else happening. Is it because I am not running any query on the `Dataframe` `dataStream` (or shall I say that the query isn't doing anything useful)?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to understand this better. Adding what I've found so far, but acknowledge this isn't a complete answer:

Streaming queries writing to a file sink write data out to the specified "path". They also require a "checkpointLocation".

```
 writer = (
    df.writeStream.format("parquet")
                  .option("path", 'filesDir')
                  .option("checkpointLocation", 'checkpointDir')
                  .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds")
)
```

What you end up is a file tree like this:

```
checkpointDir/
    commits
        .0.crc
        0
        ... (more .crc and batch files)
    offsets
        ... (.crc and batch files just like commits/)
    sources
        ... (.crc and batch files just like commits/ and offsets/)
    metadata.crc
    metadata
filesDir/
    _spark_metadata/
        .0.crc
        .1.crc
        ... (more .crc files)
        .9.compact.crc
        0
        1
        ... (more batch files)
        9.compact
    file1.parquet
    file2.parquet
    ...
```

The numeric files in the checkpointDir and _spark_metadata are named according to the micro-batch number in which they were processed. The .crc files are (I think) checksum files, though not sure how these are used.

**checkpointDir/sources**

I believe this is the first directory that gets written to when spark starts a streaming query. It lists the data sources being read from and some metadata.

**checkpointDir/offsets**

I believe spark reads from the data sources and then writes a file to this directory in order to specify that the data has been read. Each file contains metadata about the read operation such as watermark, batch-timestamp and some configuration, as well as an actual offset specifying what was read from the source.

**checkpointDir/commits**

Once the data has been processed, a commit file is generated for that batch. If a batch fails during processing, a commit file won't exist for that batch and spark will know to re-process it.

**checkpointDir/metadata**

Contains the id of the streaming query.

**_spark_metadata**

Contains a file (and crc file) for each batch processed. The file contains the destination path(s) written to and metadata about them.

Note that .compact files are generated ever N files (where N is determined by the `spark.sql.streaming.fileSink.log.compactInterval` config parameter). The compact file takes all the batch files since the last compact file and appends them to the end of the last compact file.

**Some things to note**

- Writing to the commit checkpoint dir is how spark gets At-least-once processing. Writing to the _spark_metadata dir is how it can get Exactly-Once processing.
- When starting a streaming query, the query starts after the latest *committed* offset. However, if that batch already has a file in _spark_metadata, then it is not re-processed

  - *Spark only seems to look for the existence of the batch file in _spark_metadata, it doesn't read the file or check that the files listed in it exist. EG if you delete the files from a batch, they will not be recreated so long as the metadata file for that batch exists - even if it's empty*
- I believe the batch files in _spark_metadata are actually read when initiating a streaming query from a file **source**. Spark determines which files in the source to read by looking at the metadata. This is used so as to not read partial or incomplete data. If a batch was incomplete when *writing* the data to the folder, then a batch file won't be generated in _spark_metadata and so spark will know not to read them.
- If you delete files from _spark_metadata, your job may fail down the line when it tries to create a new .compact file with an error that says the last .compact file does not exist.
- The checkpoint files do not appear to be compacted
- Spark does not cleanup metadata and you can accumulate a lot of files over time. In addition, the .compact files don't replace old files, they get added to the directory in addition to the files they are theoretically compacting. This means not only can you accumulate a lot of files, but the compact files can grow quite large as well.

**Caveats/References**

I'm not a contributor to spark nor am I particularly good at reading Java/Scala. My understanding of this is from trial and error/experimenting on my laptop, and some online articles listed below. I setup a streaming query that read from a file source and wrote to a file sync, so I don't know if the above explanation covers other scenarios. If someone has references to documentation for this that would be helpful.

https://medium.com/@Iqbalkhattra85/exactly-once-mechanism-in-spark-structured-streaming-7a27d8423560

https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/checkpoint-storage-structured-streaming/read